# MySQLInterfaceError: Python type list cannot be converted

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, mysql-python

```
    @app.route('/upload', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        file = request.files['upFile']
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))

        dir = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']+ file.filename

        cmd  = "INSERT INTO posts (title, author, file, date, subject, field ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        post = (request.form["title"], session['user_name'], dir, x, request.form["subject"], request.form.getlist("field[]"))
        crsr.execute(cmd, post)
        mydb.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('upload'))
    else:
        return render_template('upload.htm')
```

it returns : MySQLInterfaceError: Python type list cannot be converted

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To help others achieving a better solution for your problem please share more information about your issue on your post, code snippets are the best way to give other supporters a clearer image of what could be the issue

Comment: This will return a list: ` request.form.getlist("field[]")`.  Why are you retrieving a list here?  What is the datatype  of the `field` column in the database table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to convert list to string like this.

```
','.join(list)
```

Comment: This is prone to sql injection right?

Comment: @itsfarseen you are probalby right. i used it only in my backend code