# "MySQLInterfaceError: Python type list cannot be converted" on all sqlalchemy.orm.Query methods

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am running a Python 3.9.0 server through uvicorn with sqlalchemy connecting to a mysql server.

I'm trying to make queries with a `db` (session) object that I construct as such, based on examples I've pulled from the docs and web:

*database.py*

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
...
engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,
    connect_args={'auth_plugin': 'mysql_native_password'}
)
...
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

*main.py*

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from .database import SessionLocal, engine, Base

def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Per the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars), I'm trying to invoke queries as follows:

*main.py*

```
db.query(models.OriginalSong).filter_by(original_song_title=original_song_title).first()
```

However, methods such as `first()` and `all()` are throwing the same error:

```
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type list cannot be converted
```

pointing to the line where the `all()` or `first()` method was invoked.

I checked the type of the invocation and they appear to be correct:

```
print(type(db.query(models.OriginalSong).filter_by(original_song_title=original_song_title)))

<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query'>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing differently from what the [docs on the query type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.first) or the [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars). There was one [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137307/mysqlinterfaceerror-python-type-list-cannot-be-converted) I found with the same error, but trying to join the "list" just resulted in the same error. I'm not even sure what the return type of `first()` or `one()` are as it errors before I can try to print the type.

**How can I access the result of my query without an error?**

(I tried to include only the necessary code, but the full repo can be seen on [github](https://github.com/komali2/game-remix-guesser/tree/main/backend))

EDIT: Strangely, a prior query works:

```
query = db.query(models.RemixArtist).filter_by(remix_artist_name=remix_artist_name).first()
```

I don't see any difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't with the return of the query, the issue was with the parameter passed to the `filter_by`. Without realizing it, I was passing it a `list`, when it expected a `string`. I had to change the argument's value for parameter `original_song_title` to be `original_song_title[0]`.